# Nodemon This might cause high cpu usage. To reduce use --watch

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I get the warning even when I run nodemon with --watch ..

```
$nodemon app.js --watch
9 Jul 09:09:16 - [nodemon] v1.3.7
9 Jul 09:09:16 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
9 Jul 09:09:16 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
9 Jul 09:09:16 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Example app listening at http://:::3000
9 Jul 09:09:16 - [nodemon] watching 32,639 files - this might cause high cpu usage. To reduce use "--watch".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reduce the number of files that will be watched. You have to specify which directory you want to watch : https://github.com/remy/nodemon#monitoring-multiple-directories

You can also reduce this number by specifying the file extension you want to watch : 
https://github.com/remy/nodemon#specifying-extension-watch-list

Or ignore certain path like node_modules for example : 
https://github.com/remy/nodemon#ignoring-files